# using resizegather inside tabular: how to remove extra vertical space above and below the equation?

Tags: equations, gather

I need to fit some large equations generated by CAS inside a tabular.  `resizegather` seems like it can do the job. But it generates lots of extra space above and below the equation in each row.

This happens when using `\begin{gather*} ... \end{gather*}`. It does shrink the equation OK in the horizontal direction so it fits, but I am looking for a way to remove the spaces above and below.

When using `\begin{gathered} ... \end{gathered}` instead, the above and below spaces are gone, but the equation no longer shrinks !

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full]{scrbook} %same result with this also

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array} %for the m option
\usepackage{resizegather}

\begin{document}

No wasted extra space here in the vertical direction, 
but the math do not scale as expected

\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{2in}|l|}\hline
Solution & Verification\\  \hline
{$\begin{gathered} y=\sin x\tan x \int \cos x +3 x\sin x\tan x\end{gathered}$}&OK\\\hline
\end{tabular}

Here the math scales as expected to fit, but lots of extra 
wasted extra space in the vertical direction

\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{2in}|l|}\hline
Solution & Verification\\  \hline
\begin{gather*} y=\sin x \tan x\int \cos x + 3 x\sin x\tan x\end{gather*}&OK\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

listfile

```
 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2019/02/01 v3.26b KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2019/02/01 v3.26b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2019/02/01 v3.26b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2019/02/01 v3.26b KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2019/02/01 v3.26b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2019/02/01 v3.26b KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2019/02/01 v3.26b KOMA-Script package (type area)
 amsmath.sty    2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
   array.sty    2018/12/30 v2.4k Tabular extension package (FMi)
resizegather.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Resize overly large equations (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
 ***********

)
```

**Updated**

Trying the answer below, I do not see the equation shrink. Here is new MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full]{scrbook}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\setcellgapes{5pt}  
\usepackage{resizegather}      
\begin{document}

{\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}[c]{|l|l|}\hline
Solution & Verification\\  \hline
$\medmath{\begin{gathered}y=\sin x\tan x \int \cos x +3 x\sin x\tan x \sin x\tan x \int \cos x +3 x\sin x\tan x y=\sin x\tan x \int \cos x +3 x\sin x\tan x y=\sin x\tan x \int \cos x +3 x\sin x\tan x y=\sin x\tan x \int \cos x +3 x\sin x\tan x\end{gathered}}$&OK\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To long for the comment. To simulate, in what you requirement can result, please see the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full]{scrbook}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{resizegather}

\begin{document}

{
\addtolength\abovedisplayskip{-30pt}
\addtolength\belowdisplayskip{-25pt}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{0.55in}|l|}\hline
Solution & Verification \\  \hline
%\vspace*{-5ex}
\begin{gather*} 
y=\sin x \tan x\int \cos x + 3 x\sin x\tan x
\end{gather*}
%\vspace*{-4ex}
        & OK            \\   \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Result is expected ugly and useless:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Note, that `gathered` environment is inside some other math environments, so it is not visible to the package `resizegather`, so it can't influence on `gathered˙.

I suggest you another aproach, which (to my opinion) gives better result. By use of `\medmath` macro from `nccmath` package and use of `makecell` package you can obtain the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full]{scrbook}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{resizegather}

\begin{document}

No wasted extra space here in the vertical direction,
but the math do not scale as expected

{\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
Solution    & Verification  \\  
    \hline
$\medmath{
    \begin{gathered} 
y = \sin x\tan x \int\cos x +3 x\sin x\tan x
    \end{gathered} }
$           &   OK          \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}

Here the math scales as expected to fit, but lots of extra
wasted extra space in the vertical direction

\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{2in}|l|}\hline
Solution & Verification \\  \hline
\begin{gather*} 
y=\sin x \tan x\int \cos x + 3 x\sin x\tan x\end{gather*}
        & OK            \\   \hline
\end{tabular}

If you are limited with horisontal space for equation you may consider to split equation into two lines and not reduce font size to much:

{\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
Solution    & Verification  \\
    \hline
$
    \begin{multlined}
y = \sin x\tan x    \\[-3ex]
    \int\cos x dx + 3 x\sin x\tan x
    \end{multlined}
$           &   OK          \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

or with use of \verb+\medmath+:

{\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
Solution    & Verification  \\
    \hline
$\medmath{
    \begin{multlined}
y = \sin x\tan x    \\
    \int\cos x dx + 3 x\sin x\tan x
    \end{multlined} }
$           &   OK          \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is not shrinking the equation when I made the equation longer. It overflows edge of the page?  When I tried to change the table to use `p{4in}`, I get an error now. I'll post the example I used in my question at the bottom now for you to see. I used your first example in the code you posted, but make the equation longer and it did not scale as you can see.

Comment: @Nasser, you can put elephant into lady suitcase :-). I also show you, what you can do, if equation is to long: split into more lines. You have not other options (well, you can locally set font size to invisible small size. is this what you like to have?)

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in my question, these are equations generated by CAS. I read them using a program. It is not possible to edit them or modify them or do anything manually. I just needed to fit them in the space they are in (in this case, inside a table cell) using the `gather` environment or otherwise.  Only issue is that gather gives lots of empty vertical space now.